# Activate "F-lock" key on start up

Tags: hardware, keyboard, startup

Hardware: Logitech Access Keyboard, PS2, 867209-0102

[image]

I would love to be able to activate the "F-lock" key on start up (using rc.local or so).

`xev` didn't show me the key command - is there an other way to get the key command name?

Comment: I've got this exact keyboard, and I feel your pain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xev may not show the keycode for the f-lock key it's self, but it should show a different keycode for f1 with f-lock enabled vs not enabled.  Last time I read about it (a few years back) it wasn't possible to toggle f-lock from the software side, so the solution is to use xmodmap or your keybinder of choice and invert the bindings manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply ignore the <kbd>F Lock</kbd> key and get the same result whether it's on or off, you can use [my rc.local file](https://github.com/l0b0/logitech-access-keyboard-bindings) for just that purpose. I've verified in both X and VT that this works.